# Why does my controller endpoints break when I publish app to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've set up a react app service using .net core 3.1.

When I run it locally I can hit my controllers like https://localhost:5432/hello/world. If I publish the project to azure by right clicking the project and selecting "Publish" the react application loads fine on the azure website.

However, if I try to hit any of my api endpoints on azure it's as if my "endpoints.MapControllerRoute" gets completely ignored and the react router will try to navigate to the path instead.

This is my startup.cs Configure method:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
```

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

EDIT: Commenting out spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start"); locally creates the same problem as I experienced on Azure. I'm not quite sure how to get around this

Comment: and what are the url when you hit the "api endpoints on azure"?

Comment: @FrankNielsen x.azurewebsites.net/hello/world would not match any routes in the react router so it will be redirected to x.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: @user3713080 Can you use another way to deploy the project, like git or zip. I just want to confirm your publish file is correct.

Comment: Also post the network trace from browser F12..

Comment: @JasonPan I've tried deploying from an azure pipeline and set up a new app service from scratch to make sure that wasn't the issue.

Comment: @krishg If I hit the rest endpoint in a new incognito tab without first hitting the root url it hits the endpoint as expected. However if I first visit the root url and let the react page load and then hit the rest endpoint it first hits the endpoint and looking in the network tab it returns "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app." instead of "Hello world". It then loads the / page on react.

The endpoint should just returns the string "Hello World".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem and it was because I had temporarily put this code below in and forgot to add the prop "exact".

```
{env === "development" ? (
      <Route exact path='/' component={token ? () => {
        history.push(`/sign-in?token=${token}`);
        return "Loading...";
      } : Home} />
  ): (
    <Route path="/" component={() => <Redirect to={"/link"} />} />
  )}
```